# How to use regular expression parse text with symbol "| "

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse a bunch of unformatted text similar to the one below.

> those|DT|O considered|VBN|O anarchists|NNS|O at|IN|O best|JJS|O share|NN|O a|DT|O certain|JJ|O family|NN|O resemblance|NN|O .|.|O "|RQU|O

I need to use regular expression to parse the data into a format which would be like this:

> The DT I-MISC
>
> certain JJ O
>
> in IN O
>
> the DT B
>
> pound NN I

Comment: What exactly is the format you are looking for? What delineation are you trying to use? Separate by whitespace, by "|", by.... etc.?

Comment: separate by whitespace

Comment: then regex is completely overkill. Just use the "split" method and you're done. Are you sure you're also not trying to capture the "|"... it looks like you are?

Comment: `"\|"` will capture the `|` symbol any way

Comment: @en_Knight but when output the dataset i need replace "|“ with white space to match with the test data set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'wb') as outfile, open('infile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    [outfile.write(i.replace('|', ' ') + '\n')  for i in infile.read().split()]
```

You basically just want to split by whitespace then replace the | with whitespace correct? That seems to be what you're looking for.

**EDIT:**
Code now writes to file.

**EDIT 2:**
Code now reads from a file